# Программа вычисления значение полинома

Tags: c++, c, математика, полином

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    float z = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int n;
    int st = 0;
    int x = 0;
    float koef[SIZE];
    memset(koef, 0 , SIZE * sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        n = scanf("%f", &koef[i]);
        if(n == EOF)
            break;
        if(!n)
            break;
    }
    for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++)
    {
        if (koef[y] == 0)
            break;
    }
    x = koef[0];
    st += y - 2;
    z += koef[1] * pow(x, st)
       + koef[2] * pow(x, st - 1)
       + koef[3] * pow(x, st - 2)
       + koef[4] * pow(x, st - 3)
       + koef[5] * pow(x, st - 4)
       + koef[6] * pow(x, st - 5)
       + koef[7] * pow(x, st - 6)
       + koef[8] * pow(x, st - 7)
       + koef[9] * pow(x, st - 8)
       + koef[10] * pow(x, st - 9)
       + koef[11] * pow(x, st- 8)
       + koef[12] * pow(x, st - 11)
       + koef[13] * pow(x, st - 12)
       + koef[14] * pow(x, st - 13)
       + koef[15] * pow(x, st - 14)
       + koef[16] * pow(x, st - 15)
       + koef[17] * pow(x, st - 16)
       + koef[18] * pow(x, st - 17)
       + koef[19] * pow(x, st - 18)
       + koef[20] * pow(x, st - 19)
       + koef[21] * pow(x, st - 20)
       + koef[22] * pow(x, st - 21)
       + koef[23] * pow(x, st - 22)
       + koef[24] * pow(x, st - 23)
       + koef[25] * pow(x, st - 24)
       + koef[26] * pow(x, st - 25);
    printf("Vysledok je :%0.2f\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе целых чисел все работает прекрасно, но при вводе десятичных,что возможно за условием, в консоли выводит: `-nan`

Comment: Десятичные числа это другой тип)

Comment: Я вижу работает идеально. А что должно выводить? Условие задачи напишите. Что за команда `st+=y-2;` ? Тяжело догадаться что она делает. Может просто `st=y-2;` ?

Comment: Всегда пишите условие задачи - что должна делать программа. Что именно не работает. *При каких именно входных данных*. Я, конечно, вижу *неэффективную* и *эстетически ужасную* попытку вычисления значения многочлена (при этом еще и без малейших попыток форматировать код), но как знать - может, именно так и должна работать правильная программа?...

Comment: Вы как минимум переводите введенный `float` в `int x`, что уже неверно.

Comment: Как отформатировали, сразу стало видно еще одну ошибку: `+ koef[10] * pow(x, st - 9)
       + koef[11] * pow(x, st- 8)
       + koef[12] * pow(x, st - 11)` - 9-8-11... Интересно, зачем массив из 100 коэффициентов, если считается не более чем 25 степень?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вы хотите вот это? Сначала вводите x, потом коэффициенты полинома?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double z = 0;
    double x, coeff;
    int n = scanf("%lf",&x);
    if (n == EOF || n == 0) return 1;
    for(;;)
    {
        n = scanf("%lf",&coeff);
        if (n == EOF || n == 0) break;
        z = z*x+coeff;
    }
    printf("Vysledok je :%0.2lf\n", z);
}
```

И все же - на будущее - учтите мои замечания в комментарии!

Comment: `Vysledok je` вы словак?

Comment: @SKIP Это вы мне? отнюдь, природный туляк :) Но ТС именно так выводит, почему бы в этом *непринципиальном* вопросе его не поддержать? :)

Comment: не заметил, что так было в вопросе

Comment: @Harry , спасибо, очень помогли, но есть еще проблемка, при вводе: "6.7↵
3.2↵
4.1↵
5.2↵
2.1↵
4.5↵
3.6↵
↵"  ожидаемый вывод 53157.94, но программа округляет и выводит : 53157.95, не могли б подсказать, как этого избежать?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вывод `printf("Vysledok je :%0.6lf\n", z);`

Comment: @Harry , при такой команде вывода выдает "Vysledok je :53157.949634" , я прекрасно понимаю почему оно округляет, но не знаю какизбежать этого округления, так как программа проверяется автоматически, тесты требуют именно вывод 53157.94.

Comment: Ну обрежьте так: `floor(x*100.0)/100.0`

Comment: @Harry , очень признателен за помощь, все получилось.